# Nlog internal log file with custom name

Tags: logging, nlog

I am trying to create a different internal log file for each day using the `${date}` layout renderer in the `internalLogFile` name. I understand that this is possible only for a target layout. So, are there any alternate solution to this so I can automatically create a new internal log file each day, with that day's date in the file name? The file tends to get very large even for a single day, so to have one file forever would be ridiculous.

I am using asp.net-mvc-4 C# razor, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Also note that the internallog should not be that large in normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it from C#:

```
InternalLogger.LogFile = @"c:\temp\internallog.log";
```

http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.3.0/html/P_NLog_Common_InternalLogger_LogFile.htm